# Sound board with ImageButtons

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a sound board but I'm getting this error.

I might be reading the log wrong but it appears something is wrong with the image buttons.

Any ideas??

```
  01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bluffball/com.example.bluffball.Content}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at com.example.bluffball.Content.onCreate(Content.java:106)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
    01-23 15:59:03.667: E/AndroidRuntime(19712):    ... 11 more
    01-23 15:59:05.789: I/Process(19712): Sending signal. PID: 19712 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tells you quite plainly, `android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button` in your `Content.java' at line 106.

You probably have a statement there which reads something like

```
Button someButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id. ... )
```

when it should be

```
ImageButton someButton = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id. ... )
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Logcat is your friend, friend!